# How to make an image in a separate div change on hover of nav?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site I'm working on where I have a nav bar in a div at the top of the page followed by a separate div which contains an image directly below it.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to change the image by hovering over each part of the nav bar.

Basically I want an image for home to show up when the home nav feature is hovered and so on with the rest of the menu.

UPDATE:

As I tried to explain before (not as clear as I could have) I want to make each nav bar element (Home, Downloads, etc.) show a different image in the div below it. Here is the section of code for the two elements.

```
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="/about">About</a></li>
<li ><a href="/mods">Mods</a></li>
<li><a href="/forums">Forums</a></li>
<li ><a href="/downloads">Downloads</a></li>
<li><a href="//blog.blog.com">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="container" style="background: rgb(55,71,79); width:960px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 50px; border: 2px; border-radius: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hover-image white-text col s12 l6">
                <img src="homeimage.png" class="hover image" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width: 860px; max-height: 860px;"/>
        <h5 class="hover-header" style="padding-left: 20px;">Home</h2>
                <p class="hover-paragraph" style="padding-left: 25px;">Welcome to the page!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="parallax"><img src="/img/image.png"></div>

</div>

<style>
.hover-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.hover-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 10;
    width: 100%;
}
.hover-paragraph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

[Page Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkoCC.png)

Comment: PLEASE write codes to show us What you want to show.I see you are new to stackoverflow So I don't give you negative reputation but people give you negatives If you ask questions in this style and it prevents you to ask more questions.Please Update your question with your codes.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code -

CSS -

```
#navImage img{
        display:block;
        width:500px;
        height:auto;
     }
     #myNav{
       list-style-type: none;
     }
#myNav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
#myNav li a:hover {
    color:#00ffff;
}

#navImage img{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="myNav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="navImage">
      <img src="img_chania.jpg"  alt="Chania">
      <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
```

JS to initialize (with jQuery) -

```
  $("#myNav li a").on('mouseover', function(){
        $("#navImage img").hide().eq($(this).closest('li').index()).show();
    });
```

Please note, if you are working on responsive design(using bootstrap navigation), you need to do changes accordingly.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/k2zgot5r/

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! Now I just need to do the same to paragraphs alongside each image.

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS something like this;

```
.nav:hover .image{
    background-image: url('path/to/image.ext');
}
```

If you can share your code, I can be more specific.

Comment: He might want a rule like `.nav:hover + .image`, without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say.

Comment: This approach is unlikely to work if the image is in a different div separate from the one the nav is in, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Pim Thanks for Editing

Answer (score 0):

```
.myButtonLink {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('/path/to/myImage.png') bottom;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.myButtonLink:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

---

```
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#LinkURL">Leaf</a>
```

Do you want something like this. Please check this link:-http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/pure-css-image-hover/

Comment: Nope, was actually looking for a way to change a completely separate image when the button is hovered, not the button itself, thanks though.